# CRS issue with QTiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tiles

I'm trying to use QTiles to generate tiles from a shapefile layer in QGIS 2.18.1.  The tiles are for a web map, so my layer CRS is EPSG 3857.  But QGIS reports the layer extents in degrees instead of meters: `xMin,yMin -111.046,32.1004 : xMax,yMax -110.777,32.2978`.

In the JSON metadata produced by QTiles, the extents are extremely wrong:

```
{
   "maxZoom":18,
   "minZoom":0,
   "bounds":"-0.000997541174691,0.000288363206654,-0.000995126527844,0.000290135777677",
   "name":"derp",
   "format":"png"
}
```

It appears that QTiles expects the coordinates for an EPSG 3857 layer to be in meters (or EPSG 3857 pseudo-meters) and scales them down by a factor of approximately 111,320 to get degrees.  QTiles is rendering a tiny area around `0, 0` and producing only blank tiles.

If I change the layer CRS to EPSG 4326, QTiles produces tiles as expected.  But then isn't the projection slightly incorrect for a web map?